# How to add foreign key to already created table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created 2 table.Brand and Product.In both table one id is primary key and it has identity.According to foreign key constrain,it should be primary key of another table.I want to make Brandid as fk of table Product.How to do that.I have alreadyt created table.I am using sql server 2005.

```
Brand:
id : -primary key,identity
name
lname

Product :
id  :- primary key,identity
location
Brandid (id of Brand table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use [db_name] 
Go
alter table Product
add constraint Product_brandid_fk FOREIGN KEY ( Brandid ) references Brand(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT
ADD FOREIGN KEY (brandid) REFERENCES BRAND(id)
```